# The function which maps each linear isomorphism $L:V\rightarrow W$ to its pullback $L^{*}:A_{k}(W)\rightarrow A_{k}(V)$ is smooth.

Tags: linear-algebra, smooth-manifolds

Let $L:V\rightarrow W$ be an isomorphism of finite-dimensional real vector spaces. Define a linear map $L^{*}:A_{k}\left(W\right)\rightarrow A_{k}\left(V\right)$ by $L^{*}\left(\alpha\right)\left(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k}\right)\longmapsto \alpha \left(L\left(v_{1}\right),\ldots,L\left(v_{k}\right)\right)$ for all $\alpha\in A_{k}\left(W\right)
 , v_{1}
 ,...,v_{k}\in V$. Here $A_{k}\left(W\right)$ is the vector space of all alternating $k$-tensors on $V$. By fixing bases, we identify these isomorphisms with invertible matrices.

Prove that the map $^{*}:\mbox{GL}\left(n,\mathbb{R}\right)\rightarrow\mbox{GL}\left(\binom{n}{k}
 ,\mathbb{R}\right)$
  defined by $L\longmapsto L^{*}$
  is smooth as a map of smooth manifolds.

The easiest way to check if the component functions of the matrices are smooth, but I can't find a way to represent the matrices nicely.

Comment: I think you're best of doing this somewhat abstractly: you're trying to show that a (fixed) linear map between finite-dimensional vector spaces is smooth. The rest of the setting is just confusing for that problem.

Comment: I am trying to show that the map defined by $L⟼L^{*}$ is smooth, not that a specific linear map is smooth.

Comment: Yes. That is a linear map between certain vector spaces.

Comment: What are these spaces? It can't be the general linear groups because they are not closed under scalar multiplication

Comment: You've started by restricting yourself to isomorphisms. This is not necessary; the pullback map is perfectly well defined on all linear maps. After you prove it is smooth there, nothing stops you from restricting its domain. (The pullback map is a linear map between two Hom vector spaces.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more comfortable to solve a slightly more general problem.

If $L : V \to W$ is any linear map, we get an induced linear map $L^* : A_k(W) \to A_k(V)$ by pullback. This defines a map
$$
p : \operatorname{Hom}(V, W)
\to \operatorname{Hom}\bigl(A_k(W), A_k(V)\bigr),
\quad
L \mapsto L^*
$$
that I just noticed is not linear, but $k$-homogeneous, and realized that homogeneous maps are not necessarily smooth.

Oh dear.

Plan B: Coordinates. If we pick bases $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ for $V$ and $(w_1,\ldots,w_m)$ for $W$, then we can represent a linear map $L : V \to W$ by a matrix. The matrix of $L^*$ is then the transpose of the matrix of $k$-minors of the matrix of $L$. The entries of the matrix of $L^*$ are thus degree-$k$ polynomials in the entries of the matrix of $L$, so the map $L \mapsto L^*$ is smooth.

Whew.

We now note that if $L$ is an isomorphism, then so is $L^*$. This means that $p$ induces a map $\operatorname{Gl}(V,W) \to \operatorname{Gl}(A_k(W),A_k(V))$, which is also smooth because $\operatorname{Gl}(V,W) \subset \operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$ is open, and restores some semblance of the lack of effort we were going for at first.

Comment: I really thought that it was linear. I guess I never checked properly. I also tried showing that it was smooth by using matrices but I couldn't be able to find a matrix representation of $L^{*}$ given L. The large dimension was just too much for me.

Comment: You can also avoid coordinates by plan C: Polarize the wedge product. There exists a symmetric multilinear map $b : \operatorname{Hom}(V,W) \times \cdots \times \operatorname{Hom}(V,W) \to \operatorname{Hom}(A_k(W),A_k(V))$ such that your map is the restriction of $b$ to the diagonal. (You can write down this map explicitly.) Since $b$ is multilinear, it's smooth, and so is its restriction to the smooth diagonal submanifold.